# Login page does not redirect when already logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

When using stackoverflow in multiple tabs, it can occur that you're logged in in one tab but not in the other. When trying to upvote in a tab where you're not logged in, it prompts to log in. Clicking the login link, it still shows the login page, even though it perfectly well knows you're already logged in. A screenshot of the login page where I'm already logged in:

[image: Screenshot of being logged in on the login page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.3.11.2042` on meta and `2014.3.11.1445` on sites.