# Login not showing in Stack Overflow, even though I'm already logged in in stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I have an issue similar to this: *[Login page does not redirect when already logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224982/login-page-does-not-redirect-when-already-logged-in)*, but this issue was closed two years ago.

I already log in at stackexchange.com using [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), but when I navigate to stackoverflow.com, it shows as I have not logged in.

Comment: I'm not even sure if it is supposed to work that way. Base on [universal login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) you get logged in automatically on everything under *.stackexchange.com but have to re-authenticate for other domains like StackOverflow, Super User and ServerFault. For me it looks like it works as designed.

Comment: but it used to work before :(

Comment: You [might be right](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5213320#5213320) we need to wait for a dev to confirm.

Comment: Even when i click on stackoverflow link from stackexchange.com site drop-down link it asking for login.

Comment: Any number of things could have happened here. Maybe you lost cookies on stackoverflow.com? What happens if you log out and log back in?

Comment: You can also just log in on stackoverflow.com, that should also fix things back up.